# itext7 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.esf.SignaturePolicyIdentifier

Tags: android, android-studio, itext, itext7

I want to use `iText7` in `Android Studio`, and I added this module into `build.gradle`.

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:io:7.0.4'
compile 'com.itextpdf:kernel:7.0.4'
compile 'com.itextpdf:layout:7.0.4'
compile 'com.itextpdf:sign:7.0.4'
```

But the source code about `PDFSigner` looks like this:

[image]

And I get following **error** message:

[image]

Can someone help, please? Thanks.

Comment: This usually means that you have a missing or incompatible version of BouncyCastle or SpongyCastle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , I go to [LATEST JAVA RELEASES](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) to download the file which named **bcprov-jdk15on-158.jar** to solve this problem .

Comment: Glad to see that you were able to solve the problem.

Comment: If someone finds this answer in the future, though, the correct approach is not to take the *latest* bc version but the one *matching your iText version*! The maven pom file dependencies will show you which that is.